# How to incorporate "weighted study" into plot graph

Tags: r, metadata, lattice, scatter-plot, mixed-mode

My data were collected from the literature for a meta-analysis:

```
 Study      Eeff        Neff   Weight (%)
    1   34.83181476 50.04959144 0.1
    1   33.76824264 49.53210571 0.1
    1   32.67390287 47.77214774 0.1
    1   33.05520666 47.30254996 0.1
    2   33.19730252 44.21602149 0.3
    2   34.04709188 44.48002926 0.3
    3   33.22501606 38.96770954 0.3
    3   33.80766289 41.66974683 0.3
    3   33.06675158 42.66282841 0.3
    3   32.43069645 37.06958147 0.3
    4   34.72367611 41.31151977 0.25
    4   33.93254846 43.8526145  0.25
    4   33.22982756 44.99923374 0.25
    4   32.85979541 46.35648939 0.25
    5   32.85979541 43.53737788 0.35
    5   32.85979541 44.16612955 0.35
    5   32.85979541 40.10215682 0.35
    5   32.85979541 39.05910344 0.35
```

I have `Eeff` and `Neff` were obtained from 5 studies. First I made a scatter plot between `Eeff` and `Neff` normally. However, since data came from different studies where different sample size, experimental conditions...I weighted study by "inverse variance", i.e. the larger the variance the lesser the weight. Total weight is 100% (or 1). 
I want to make a new scatter plot where this "weight" could be included? Could someone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using [`ggplot2`](http://ggplot2.org/), could do something like:

```
require('ggplot2')
aFile = read.table('yourdata.txt',header = T)     
p=ggplot(aFile,aes(Eeff,Neff))
p + geom_point(aes(colour = Weight,size = Weight))
```

Obviously you will want to play with colors and marker size, etc....

[image]